# Who should I contact to use clips from the Gazebo youtube channel?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am doing a project and need to create an overview video of Gazebo. I would like to use clips from Gazebo's own youtube channel. Is there someone I should get expressed permission from or am I good to use it?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17817/who-should-i-contact-to-use-clips-from-the-gazebo-youtube-channel?/) by [billybilly](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4123/billybilly/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

Thanks for the question. You are free to use anything on Gazebo's youtube channel:

https://www.youtube.com/c/GazeboSim

-nate

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2017-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2